# Validation of a checkbox with node-validator, node-mailer and ejs

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs, node-modules

Here's my problem:

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')
const { matchedData } = require('express-validator/filter')
const csrf = require('csurf');
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

router.get('/contact', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact', {
    data: {},
    errors: {},
    errorMap: {},
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
  });
});

router.post('/contact', csrfProtection, [
  check('message')
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage('Message is required')
    .trim(),
  check('name')
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage('Name is required')
    .trim(),
  check('email')
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('That email doesn‘t look right')
    .trim()
    .normalizeEmail(),
  check('checkNews')
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.render('contact', {
      data: req.body,
      errors: errors.array(),
      errorMap: errors.mapped(),
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
    })
  }
  
  ..
```

```html
<div class="form-header">
  <% if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) { %>
  <h2>Send us a message</h2>
  <% } else { %>
  <h2 class="errors-heading">Oops, please correct the following:</h2>
  <ul class="errors-list">
    <% Object.values(errors).forEach(error => { %>
    <li><%= error.msg %></li>
    <% }) %>
  </ul>
  <% } %>
</div>
<form method="post" action="/contact" novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
  <div class="form-field <%= errors.message ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="input" id="message" name="message" rows="4" autofocus><%= data.message %></textarea>
    <% if (errors.message) { %>
    <div class="error"><%= errors.message.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>



  <div class="form-field <%= errors.name ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="name" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="<%= data.name %>" />
    <% if (errors.name) { %>
    <div class="error"><%= errors.name.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-field <%= errors.checkNews ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="checkNews">Subscribe to newsletter</label>
    <input class="checkNews" id="checkNews" name="checkNews" type="checkbox" value=" <%= data.checkNews ? 'want' : 'ego' %>" />
    <% if (errors.checkNews) { %>
    <div class="error"><%= errors.checkNews.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>




  <div class="form-field <%= errors.email ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="input" id="email" name="email" type="email" value="<%= data.email %>" />
    <% if (errors.email) { %>
    <div class="error"><%= errors.email.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  console.log(document.querySelector('#checkNews').value)
</script>
```

A lot of stuff is happening here but I would like to focus on the ejs template:

```
<div class="form-field <%= errors.checkNews ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
    <label for="checkNews">Subscribe to newsletter</label>
    <input class="checkNews" id="checkNews" name="checkNews" type="checkbox" value=" <%= data.checkNews ? 'cat' : 'dog' %>" />
    <% if (errors.checkNews) { %>
    <div class="error"><%= errors.checkNews.msg %></div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
```

The value will be output at the moment of the validation, but I need to get a value, depends on an if statement to get the value, if it true or not.

In this case, the only thing that I was able to fetch was the dog string, in the other case the value is undefined.

How come and how can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You mean you want to make all the `<div>` in each column the same height? Or you want to align the title, images and text vertically (like table rows)?

Comment: There is **NO** CSS method of aligning elements or equalising heights of elements that do not share a parent. You need Javascript.

Comment: Just same height for the <p> inside the <div>